# In Spark 1.6 how to avoid data skew issue and evenly distribute the data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

Hi I am reading a sequence file containing json format record, when reading the json record converting into Dataframe  causing data skew issue as you can see form Spark UI screen shot. How to avoid this data skew issue ?

```
val src = sc.sequenceFile(FilePath, classOf[Text], classOf[Text] )
val df = sqlCntxt.read.json(src)
```

261 Completed tasks

```
Metric  Min 25th Percentile Median  75th Percentile Max
Duration    47 ms   0.1 s   5 s 25 s    **1.0 min**
GC Time 0 ms    0 ms    0 ms    0.1 s   0.7 s
Input Size/ Records 438.0 B/1   1013.0 B /2 1776.0 B/ 12    128.2 MB / 277608   **128.5 MB / 1162416**
Shuffle Write size/Records  240.0 B/1   446.0 B /1  509.0 B / 1 622.0 B /1  **2.3 KB /1**
```

Comment: Code you posted wouldn't  type check and compile.

Answer (score -1):

There cannot be a data skew if you are not performing any join operation. Looks like you are just trying to read the JSON file.

You encounter a skewed data issue when you try to join an abnormally huge dataset with a very small dataset or when the data is distributed unevenly based on your join condition.